# Java - Cannot display user input data as an output table using classes

Tags: java, class, oop, object, methods

**UPDATE -** Thanks for the suggestions. At least now my program runs without major errors.

When items stored reaches 3 sets of data, program terminates and displays output table. However, only the titles are displayed and wondering how I would fetch the user input data of each element, and display under each column column heading stored within ChessList.java but going through ChessMain.java (As like the table headings stored within ChessList.java)
Any suggestions. Thanks

ChessMain.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChessMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       ChessList listOfNumbers = new ChessList("");
       boolean finished = false;

       for(int i = 0; i <2; i++) {

           System.out.print("Enter piece number: \t ");
           int pieceNum = input.nextInt();


            System.out.print("Enter row number for piece " + pieceNum +  ": \t ");
            int rowNum = input.nextInt(); 
            input.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Enter a column number for piece " + pieceNum + ": \t ");
            int columnNum = input.nextInt(); 
            input.nextLine(); 


           } 

       System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
       listOfNumbers.printTable();


    }
}
```

Chess.java

```
public class Chess {
    private int pieceNum;
    private int rowNum;
    private int columnNum;

    // piece 
    public int getpieceNum(){
        return pieceNum;
    }

    public void setpieceNum(int piece){
        pieceNum = piece;
    }

    // row
     public int getrowNum(){
        return rowNum;
    }

    public void setrowNum(int row){
        rowNum = row;
    }

    // column
     public int getcolumnNum(){
        return columnNum;
    }

    public void setcolumnNum(int column){
        columnNum = column;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Piece " + pieceNum + " Row " + rowNum + " Column " + columnNum;
    }


}
```

ChessList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChessList {
    private ArrayList<Chess> chessList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String listName; 
    public ChessList(String name) {
        this.listName = name;
    }

 /*
     public void addChess(int piece, int row, int column){
        Chess newPiece = new Chess(piece, row, column);
        chessList.add(newPiece);
    }

    */
    public String toString(){
        String valueString = "\nThe chessboard holds the follwing assets:\n";
        for(Chess elem : chessList){
            valueString += elem + " \n";
        }
        return valueString;
    }

    public void printTable(){
        System.out.println("Piece\tRow\tColumn");
**// BELOW CODE DOES NOT DISPLAY USER INPUT DATA AS AN OUTPUT OF EACH PIECE, ROW, COLUMN** 
        for(Chess elem : chessList){
            System.out.println(elem.getname() + "\t" + elem.getrowNum() + "\t" + elem.getcolumnNum() + "\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "constructor ChessList in class ChessList cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: java.lang.String".

Answer (score 0):

```
ChessList listOfNumbers = new ChessList("Chessboard");
```

needs to be changed to

```
ChessList listOfNumbers = new ChessList();
```

since ChessList does not have a constructor that takes a String parameter.

OR you could implement a constructor that saves a String:

```
public class ChessList {
    private ArrayList<Chess> chessList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String listName; // Type changed to String!

    public ChessList(String name) {
        this.listName = name;
    }

    // Your other mothods here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object ChessList doesn't have a constructor. In Java it sets up a default constructor that takes no parameters. Which is what you are trying to use but you are passing it a String.

Should be this:

```
ChessList listOfNumbers = new ChessList();
```

If you want to pass a String to the constructor to set a name for the ChessList then you need to create a constructor in your ChessList class that accepts a String.